# C++/CLI unit test code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, c++-cli, code-coverage

I have a question about code coverage analysis for C++/CLI unit testing.

I have followed the following tutorial in order to set up code coverage:
**http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2011/08/16/capturing-c-code-coverage-with-visual-c.aspx**

The first thing I did was create three project:

- Proj 1 - A static library project that contains the code I want to test.
- Proj 2 - An application project (exe) that calls the code in Proj 1.
- Proj 3 - The unit test project that tests the code from Proj 1.

In Proj 1 I simply have a header file with the following code:

```
int ToTest()
{
    return 5;
}
```

In Proj 2 I have just this simple main:

```
int main()
{
    ToTest();
    return 0;
}
```

And finally in Proj 3 I have the following unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert::IsTrue(ToTest() == 5);
};
```

(The above is based on this tutorial: 
**http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx**)

I have followed the first tutorial, and changed the properties of Proj 2 to have the Profile option on and the (/OPT:NOREF) option as well. I edited the settings of the localtestrun and configured the code coverage by adding the .exe of Proj 3.

I run the unit test, and clicked on the code coverage results. The result I got is the following:

**Empty results generated: none of the instrumented binary was used. Look at test run details for any instrumentation problems.**

Anyone got any idea why I'm getting this result?

I have even tried to move the `ToTest` function to Proj 2 and unit test it, but still no results.

Hope someone can Help.

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind actually. It turns out I need to change the test project settings (proj 3) to have the profiling on as well.

Comment: Please @p-p, close your question if solved. Thanks.

Comment: @smonff It can prove useful for others if they face the same problem, therefore I am leaving it open.